# When eclipse moxy jar is present in class path, then jersey jackson provider is not considered

Tags: java, date, eclipselink, unmarshalling, jackson-databind

We have code(*my team don't have control over*) which uses JacksonJsonProvider class to de serialize the REST response. But what I observe is when I have eclipse moxy core jar is present in my classpath, then when readEntity method is called, instead of going into Jackson class to unmarshall the response, it goes into Eclipse Unmarshaller.

The main problem, that I am facing because of this is, in my response I have a field which return date value(as long) from DB, when unmarshalled, the value is not set(null).
The DTO class have field of type java.util.Date.

What possible options do I have?

Following is client code:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
GenericType<List<PublicationDTO>> abcd = new GenericType<List<PublicationDTO>>() {};
clientConfig.register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
clientConfig.register("application/json");

Client _client2 = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
WebTarget _webTarget2 = _client2.target("....");
Response resp = _webTarget2.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get();
List<PublicationDTO> data = resp.readEntity(abcd);
data.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output: <every thing except date works; date is null.>

DTO class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PublicationDTO {
  private Long publicationId;
  
  @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
  private Date startTime;

  @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
  private Date endTime;
```

Following is stack trace of classes that were called, when I make readEntity when eclipse moxy core lib is present in classpath.

[image: EclipsereadEntity]

Following is when not:

[image: jacksonStackTrace]

PS: I cannot remove eclipse moxy core jar, because my project needs that to unmarshall some response. Because of this other project which I don't have control over is failing with the response. Both have same class loader for loading their jars and classes. (if you have worked on SAP Hybris, you know how classloading work there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we are using Jersey, from GlassFish v4, the default implementation considered is Eclipse Link Moxy. If we want to choose Jackson, then register client object with JacksonFeature.

For e.g.`client.register(JacksonFeature.class);`